# natural isomorphism by right exactness

Tags: category-theory, tensor-products, local-rings

*R* is a local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ and residue field *k*.
*M* is a finitely generated *R*-module with a projective cover:
$0 \to$ *N* $\to$ *F* $\to$ *M* $\to 0$.

Tensor $0\to$ $\mathfrak{m}$ $\to$ *R* $\to $ *k* $\to 0$ by *N*; right exactness gives a natural isomophism
$\tau_N$: *N* $\otimes_R$ *k* $\to$ *N*/$\mathfrak{m}$*N*

I am not sure how to reach the last natural isomorphism by right exactness. I don't think the answer here
[Showing that if $R$ is a commutative ring and $M$ an $R$-module, then $M \otimes_R (R/\mathfrak m) \cong M / \mathfrak m M$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150114/showing-that-if-r-is-a-commutative-ring-and-m-an-r-module-then-m-otimes) is correct as M might not be flat.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you think flatness is needed for the argument you linked?

Comment: Hi. I got this corollary from P139 of Rotman's Intro to Homological Algebra. Thx!

Comment: You are learning MathJax. Good. But you should put one's entire formula within dollars, not just individual symbols, otherwise (i) the formula comes out spaced badly, (ii) you create pointless extra work for yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your hints Seng! You are the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By tensoring your exact sequence by $N$ you get an exact sequence
$$N\otimes_R\mathfrak{m}\to N\otimes_RR\to N\otimes(R/\mathfrak{m})\to0$$
by right-exactness. This means that $N\otimes(R/\mathfrak{m})$
is isomorphic to the cokernel of $\phi:N\otimes_R\mathfrak{m}\to N\otimes_RR$.
The image of $\phi$ is generated by the elements of the form $m\otimes a$
with $n\in N$ and $a\in\mathfrak{m}$.

Now $N\otimes_RR$ is isomorphic to $N$ via the map taking $n\otimes a$ to $an$.
Under this isomorphism the image of $\phi$ corresponds to the submodule $N'$
of $N$ generated by the $an$ for $a\in\mathfrak{m}$ and $n\in N$, that is $N'=\mathfrak{m}N$. So the cokernel of $\phi$ is isomorphic to $N/N'$
which is isomorphic to $N/\mathfrak{m}N$. But this cokernel is also
isomorphic to $N\otimes_R(R/\mathfrak{m})\cong N\otimes_Rk$.