# Why does $A_s = k[U,T,S]/(UT-S) \otimes_{k[S]} k[S]/(S-s)$ simplify to $ A_s = k[U,T] / (UT-s)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

When reading algebraic geometry (on the technique of base change) in the book *Algebraic Geometry 1 - Schemes* by Ulrich Gortz, et.al, I came up with the following tensor product:
$$
A_s = k[U,T,S]/(UT-S) \otimes_{k[S]} k[S]/(S-s), \quad \quad (\star)
$$
and the author claimed that
$$
A_s = k[U,T] / (UT-s).      \quad \quad (\star\star)
$$
My **question** is: how to simplify $(\star)$ to $(\star\star)$?

More on this question:

I have read Atiyah and MacDonald's Comm. Algebra and know what a tensor product is. Yet I have not been familiar with the concrete calculation of tensor products (though I know the universal property of tensor products, its relation with localization, its exactness and etc.)

So beside the above question, I hope to know that **what is going on in your mind when calculating the tensor product**?

For example, when calculating the quotient ring $k[x,y]/(y-x^2)$, we can imagine that $y-x^2 = 0$ and hence $y=x^2$, then in the ring $k[x,y]$, we can make $y$ be $x^2$ and the quotient ring is isomorphic to $k[x]$.

For example, when calculating the quotient ring $k[x,y]/(1-xy)$, we can imagine that $xy=1$ and hence $y=1/x$, then in the ring $k[x,y]$, we can make $y$ be $1/x$ and the quotient ring is isomorphic to $k[x, 1/x]$, or the localization $k[x]_{x}$.

Then, when calculating the tensor product, is there a way like these above in mind to help us calculate these?

Thank you all! :)

Comment: I haven't tried, but the first thing that comes to my mind is trying to prove that the given ring satisfies the universal property of the tensor product.

Comment: In my head, when I see this specific tensor product, I see that the $S$ on the left hand side is identified with the $S$ on the right hand side. Since $S = s$ in $k[S]/(S - s),$ this tensor is essentially given by setting $S = s$ in the left hand factor. To formalize the argument, look to the answers below.

Comment: @Stahl Thank you! It is much clearer combining your comments with the answer by tkf.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz  Thank you for your comments and that really works! Yet unfortunately, it is occasionally the case that we do not know the simplified result of $A_s$ in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We may also solve this problem without touching any elements in these specific rings: we have that [$R/I\otimes_R M\cong M/IM$ by the map sending $(r+I)\otimes m \mapsto rm+IM$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150114/showing-that-if-r-is-a-commutative-ring-and-m-an-r-module-then-m-otimes), and as $(R/I)/J(R/I)\cong R/(I,J)$, we have the desired result.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer! It should be a useful "isomorphism theorem" to be memorized. Yet it seems that the point is I am not familiar with the "magic" isomorphism $R/I \otimes_R M \cong M/IM$. It is quite hard for me to get command of "all" these isomorphisms. I wonder how one comes up with the right isomorphism theorem once seeing the problem, or is it just rely on one's experience on these stuff?

Comment: You're welcome. I think it's just experience (plus having a professor/instructor who makes sure to emphasize the important isomorphisms like this, maybe).

Comment: Ok, thank you! :)

Answer (score 5):

An arbitrary element of $A_s$ is a $k$-linear combination of elements of the form $p(U,T)S^i\otimes 1$, where $p$ is a polynomial over $k$, in two variables.  As we are tensoring over $k[S]$, we have the equality:
\begin{eqnarray*}p(U,T)S^i\otimes 1&=&p(U,T)\otimes S^i\\&=&p(U,T)\otimes s^i\\&=&p(U,T)s^i\otimes 1\end{eqnarray*}

Thus in effect we substitute in $s$ for $S$ in the ring $k[U,T,S]/(UT-S)$, resulting in $k[U,T]/(UT-s)$.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer!