# For a prime ideal $\def\p{\mathfrak{p}}\p\subset A$ and a ring map $A\to B$, what is $B_\p/\p B_\p$? Can $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal of $B$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm studying Gortz, Algebraic Geometry 1, p. 351 Lemma 12.74

[image]

[image]

In the underlined statement, what $\operatorname{Spec}B_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}B_\mathfrak{p}$? $\mathfrak{p}$ can be a prime ideal of $B$? In general, prime ideal of a subring need not be a prime ideal of the ambient ring. In case of 'integrally closed subring', or "$B$ is of the form $A[b]$", can it be possible?

If so,  how can we deduce $f^{-1}(y) \cong X \times_{Y} \operatorname{Spec}k(y) \cong \operatorname{Spec}(B\otimes _Ak(y))\cong \operatorname{Spec}(B\otimes_AA_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}) \cong \operatorname{Spec}(B_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}B_\mathfrak{p})$ (the last step)?

Comment: I would guess that $B_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is “simply” $A_{\mathfrak{p}} \otimes_A B$, but that’s not sure. Certainly, $\mathfrak{p}$ can be a prime ideal of $B$ (eg $A$ is a field, $B=A[T]$), but it’s far from necessary (see $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}[1/2]$).

Comment: Uhm. I'm guessing so too. But I'm also not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}\subset A$, for any $A$-module $M$ we can define $M_\mathfrak{p}=M\otimes_A A_\mathfrak{p}$ to be the localization of $M$ at $\mathfrak{p}$. Since a ring map $A\to B$ makes $B$ in to an $A$-module (even an $A$-algebra), $B_\mathfrak{p}$ is just $B\otimes_A A_\mathfrak{p}$.

Similarly, for any $A$-module $M$ and any ideal $I\subset A$, we can ask about the submodule $IM\subset M$ and take the quotient to get the module $M/IM$. As $B_\mathfrak{p}$ is an $A$-module and $\mathfrak{p}\subset A$ is an ideal, we apply that procedure and get $B_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}B_\mathfrak{p}$.

This also tells you exactly how to deduce the line of math that you're concerned about: writing $k(y)=A_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}$, we have that $B\otimes_A k(y) \cong B\otimes_A A_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}$. Next, writing $A_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}\cong A_\mathfrak{p} \otimes_A A/\mathfrak{p}$, we can write $B\otimes_A A_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}\cong B\otimes_A A_\mathfrak{p} \otimes_A A/\mathfrak{p}\cong B_\mathfrak{p}\otimes_A A/\mathfrak{p} \cong B_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}B_\mathfrak{p}$ since [$M\otimes_R R/I\cong M/IM$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150114/showing-that-if-r-is-a-commutative-ring-and-m-an-r-module-then-m-otimes).

There's no need to worry about whether $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal (or even an ideal at all!) in $B$. For instance, if $A=\Bbb Z$ and $B=\Bbb Z[1/2]$, the image of the ideal $\mathfrak{p}=(2)\subset A$ is not even an ideal in $B$.

Comment: O.K. Thanks. And I have some more questions. Q.1)  $B_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}B_\mathfrak{p}$ has structure of ring, so that $\operatorname{Spec}(B_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}B_\mathfrak{p})$ is defined?

Comment: Q.2) $A_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p} \cong  A_\mathfrak{p} \otimes_A A/\mathfrak{p}$ as $A$-algebra?

Comment: Q.3) As you noted, $B_\mathfrak{p} \otimes_A A/\mathfrak{p} \cong B_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}B_\mathfrak{p} $ as '$A$-module'. This isomorphism can be also '$A$-algebra' isomorphism?

Comment: Yes to all three. The verifications are quite straightforward: the obvious maps all do the right thing.

Comment: Yes. Perhaps, can we find explicit isomorphism $A_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p} \cong A_\mathfrak{p} \otimes A/\mathfrak{p}$? 
   My first attempt is $(f/g + \mathfrak{p}A_{\mathfrak{p}}) \mapsto (f/g \otimes (1+\mathfrak{p}))$. Then, for example, surjectivity is ; for $(f/g \otimes (a+\mathfrak{p})) \in A_\mathfrak{p} \otimes A/\mathfrak{p}$, $(a \cdot f/g + \mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}) \mapsto (f/g \otimes (a+\mathfrak{p}))$. Is it correct?

Comment: Looks like you figured it out yourself - why do you need my approval for it?

Comment: That is, just I am not certainly sure.  Anyway Thanks !