Given $R =\mathbb{Z}$, $M = \mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$ and $N = \mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$, show if $M \otimes_R N$ is zero or not.

Given $R =\mathbb{Z}$, $M = \mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$  and $N = \mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$
. Show if $M \otimes_R N$ is zero or not.
$\otimes_R$ is the Tensor product over R here $\mathbb{Z}$ .
I tried to see if i can use the chinese lemma to make 9 = 3*3 and 12 = 3 * 2 *2 and see if i can look at the smaller products which was only more confusing.
looking at the annihilator of M and N respectively 9 and 12 and their gcd being 3 i believe there should be a Isomorphism of $M \otimes_R N$ to $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ but I‘m not wure how that helps and how I show this isomophism


Please give context, show your attempts or at least describe the meaning of the symbol $\otimes_R$.

Your question is phrased as an isolated question and has the style of "here is my problem; solve it for me". These questions are generally not well-received on MSE. Please show us your attempts or ideas to tackle the problem and tell us what kind of knowledge you have so that the hints can be given accordingly.

I have added my attempts, because of how chaotic they are I thought they wouldn‘t really help

If the isomorphism above exists would that be a proof that It‘s not zero, as i can use the universal property and show it isn‘t mapped to 0?

See if this answers your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150114

The isomorphism $M\otimes N\to \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ is given by  $1\otimes1\mapsto 1$.  Yes checking the universal property is a good way to verify this.  Note a bilinear map $M\times N\to A$ is determined by the image of $(1,1)$, and a homomorphism $ \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ is determined by the image of $1$.  From here you just need to show they are in bijective correspondence.

yes, thanks that helps alot

More generally, $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/\gcd(m,n)\mathbb{Z}$ for any two positive integers $m$ and $n$.
